# C++: Cannot return a shared_ptr to an object from a const method

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am trying to return a `shared_ptr` to an object of type `Group`, from a method that has `const` in it's declaration (a requirement in this project).
`Group` objects are stored in a class property `mySet<Group> groups`, `mySet` is just an implementation of `std::set` (also a requirement). I have tried to approach the task from all angles, but can't seem to find a working solution.

I omitted non relevant methods and properties to keep it minimal and clear.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Group> GroupPointer;
typedef mySet<Group>::const_iterator cgIterator;

class Clan{
    std::string name;
    mySet<Group> groups;
    public:
    const GroupPointer& getGroup(const std::string& group_name) const;
};

class Group{
   std::string name;
   public:
   const std::string& getName() const;
};

const GroupPointer& Clan::getGroup(const std::string& group_name) const{
    cgIterator  itr = groups.begin();
    for(; itr != groups.end(); itr++){
        if((*itr).getName() == group_name){
            GroupPointer* pptr = new GroupPointer(new Group(*itr));
            return *pptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are actually returning a reference to `shared_ptr`. What is your question anyway?

Comment: Why do you allocate the shared_ptr itself on the heap?

Comment: @manni66 Best create a shared/unique pointer for that shared ptr....

Comment: std::set owns its elements. shared_ptr owns (jointly with other shared_ptrs) what it points to. You cannot have both at the same time.  The only way you can use shared_ptr is by having std::set *of* shared_ptrs.

Comment: @n.m. Many many thanks! You pointed the error. Could you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::set` owns its elements. `std::shared_ptr` owns (jointly with other `shared_ptr`s) what it points to. You cannot have both at the same time. The only sensible way to use `std::shared_ptr` in this setting is to have an `std::set<std::shared_ptr<Group>>` .

Answer (score 2):

First, do not allocate the pointer itself on the heap.
Use `std::make_shared()`

```
GroupPointer pptr = std::make_shared<Group>(Group(*itr));
```

Because this instance of the shared ptr will go out of scope and will be destroyed it is better to return it by value instead of a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what you are currently returning

```
GroupPointer* pptr = new GroupPointer(new Group(*itr));
return *pptr;
```

You have a *reference* to a *dynamically allocated* `shared_ptr`, which is currently the *unique* owner of a *copy* of an element of your set.

There is a couple of sensible options, and some less sensible

- Change `groups` to `mySet<std::shared_ptr<Group>>`

  - You should strongly consider changing the return type of `Clan::getGroup` to just `std::shared_ptr<Group>`. Would you write a method `Group * const & someMethod(...)`?
- Change `Clan::getGroup` to return a `Group const &`

Both of these allow you to `return *itr;` when you find an element

Less sensibly

- just `return std::make_shared(*itr);`